# JavaのJREとJDKの違い

Tags: java

JREとJDKの違いが、いまいち分かっていません。
JREは実行時に必要、JDKは開発時に使う、JREはJDKに含まれている、というような、[ここに書かれているような内容](http://www.task-notes.com/entry/20140810/1407599796)程度のことは分かっています。

開発環境にJDKが必要なのは間違いないと思いますが、では、本番環境は常にJREを使うべきなのでしょうか？
ここで想定しているアプリケーションは、JBossEAPなどの上で動くウェブアプリケーションであり、本番環境とは、自社で運営するクラウドサービスのサーバであったり、顧客に社内に構築されたサーバであったり、というものです。

「JREは実行時に必要、JDKは開発時に使う、JREはJDKに含まれている」という程度の知識しか無いため、本番環境は常にJREにすべきなのか、JDKを使っても良いのか、あるいはJDKを使う方が良いケースがあるのか、その判断基準がありません。

この判断基準となるような、具体的な違いを知りたいです。

また、OracleJDKのサポートサイクル（バグフィックスやセキュリティパッチのリリース）が変更になりますが、この点についても疑問があります。
もし本番環境にはJREしか使わない場合、開発環境のJDKにセキュリティパッチが当たらなかったとして、本番環境にはどのような影響があるのでしょう？
本番環境のJREにきちんとパッチがあたっていれば、アプリケーションの運用には特に問題が無いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ミドルウェアなどの動作にJDKが必要であればJDKを使いますが、基本的にそれらはJREだけで動くようにつくってあるはずなので、JREだけで十分です。ただし、障害時の解析に必要なjstackやjmapなどのコマンドはJDKに含まれているので、JDKを入れた方が無難です。

ちなみに、JBoss EAPはJDKの使用を推奨していますが、JREでも問題なく動作するはずです

[参考]
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/18259

> もし本番環境にはJREしか使わない場合、開発環境のJDKにセキュリティパッチが当たらなかったとして、本番環境にはどのような影響があるのでしょう？
>   本番環境のJREにきちんとパッチがあたっていれば、アプリケーションの運用には特に問題が無いのでしょうか？

本番環境のシステムがJREだけで動作するのであれば、JDK（JREではない部分）にセキュリティ脆弱性があっても問題はありません。

Answer (score 1):

> OracleJDKのサポートサイクル（バグフィックスやセキュリティパッチのリリース）が変更になりますが、この点についても疑問があります。
>   もし本番環境にはJREしか使わない場合、開発環境のJDKにセキュリティパッチが当たらなかったとして、本番環境にはどのような影響があるのでしょう？
>   本番環境のJREにきちんとパッチがあたっていれば、アプリケーションの運用には特に問題が無いのでしょうか？

（ややこしい話なので自信がありません。違うぞという方は訂正をお願いします。）

まず変更されたのはOracleJDKだけではなくOracle Java SE全体の話なのでJREのサポートも影響を受けます。Java SEのサポート期限が切れるとJDKだけでなくJREのパッチも提供されなくなります。JREにパッチを当てるには最新もしくはLTSのJava SEに移行する必要があります。そしてその最新もしくはLTSのOracleJDKが有償になるという話ではないでしょうか？
有償サポート契約を結ぶか無償のOpenJDKを使用すれば問題ありませんが、その場合はそもそもこのような質問には至らないはずですし…。

Answer (score 1):

Server JRE という本番環境用？のJREもあります。
一般論ですが、特に理由がなければServer JREを使い、ソフトウェアの要件でJDKが必要な場合はJDKを入れるというのが良いかと思います。